# C++ When iput complete name it only shows the first name and not printing the second name

Tags: c++

When I tried to input in the first name and last name in the string it, once I run it, the program only outputs the first name and does not output the second name or word.

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ClassOne
{
    public:
    void setName(string xName)
        {
            name = xName;
        }
        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
};

int main()
{
    string inputName;
    cout << "Please input your name: ";
    cin >> inputName;
    ClassOne objClassOne;
    objClassOne.setName(inputName);
    cout << "Your Name is " << objClassOne.getName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Once I input Michael Jordan it only shows Michael

I'm just a beginner in C++.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `std::getline(cin,inputName)` instead  of `cin >> inputName;`

Comment: `cin >> inputName;` will stop reading when it encounters a whitespace character. You will need to use `getline(cin, inputName);`.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help.